# How to track facebook ad performance

Tags: facebook, tracking

I have a facebook ad that targets my facebook fan page. Some of the users that click on may ad will also go to my website and register themselves.

How can I can track how many vitors registered, that came to my site via specific facebook ad?

Answer (score 0):

When you generate the link for the ad that redirects them to your site add some sort of information to the query string. Then when they hit your site you can check for the query string parameter and save it in their session. Thus is they register you can check the information in the session and if they were redirected from facebook then you can log that.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I alredy did what you are suggesting, but it didn't work for me. While I successfully recorded number of registrations that came via facebook ad, number of FB Like-s started to decline, because when facebook users click on Like for my ad, that was not registered as a "like" for my facebook page, but as "like" for the url that was set on that specific ad. That was a huge drawback for this solution.

Comment: What about using the HTTP_REFERER? Check if they came from Facebook and if they did then you know the clicked your ad? That way you can keep your URL consistent